# In terms of replication, can an OpenLDAP consumer act as a provider to another OpenLDAP server?

Tags: ldap, replication

If I have an OpenLDAP server configured as a replication provider and a second OpenLDAP server configured as a consumer, can I configure the second server to act as a provider for a third OpenLDAP server?  If so, is there minimum OpenLDAP version for which this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the database has the 'syncprov' overlay loaded. This is actually how multi-master (multi-provider) replication works in OpenLDAP – all nodes in the cluster are simultaneously providers for every other node *and* consumers of every other node.

So if your version of OpenLDAP supports MMR (which 2.4.x certainly does), then it also supports the simpler case of chained replication in the same manner.

From the [OpenLDAP admin guide](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/guide.html#Replication):

> provider/consumer roles are quite fluid: replication updates received in a consumer can be further propagated by that consumer to other servers, so a consumer can also act simultaneously as a provider

Comment: If the second server as a consumer is using an overlay such as 'rwm' or 'memberOf' does this make any difference to the data it can provide to to the third server?

Comment: I really don't know how syncprov interacts with rwm; it probably depends on the order of the two overlays (i.e. my guess would be that it can be either stacked below syncprov, or above it). As for memberOf, its documentation says "using this in a replicated environment is explicitly discouraged" (OpenLDAP 2.6.x deprecates memberOf in favor of improved 'dynlist').